# how to make trigger on google app script will be active in the last day of the month?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i want to make trigger for my script will be run in last day every month, i m so confuse because there are not option for last day, but a number 1 up to 31.. if i select "31", it would be error when month just 28, 29, or 30. please help me...[trigger options1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8nox.png)

[trigger options for selecting day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlXmg.png)

please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a daily trigger and start you function like this:

```
function runsOnLastDayOfMonth() {//run  with  a daily trigger
  const dt = new Date();
  const dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate()).valueOf();
  const dtldomv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth() + 1, 0).valueOf();
  if (dtv == dtldomv) {
    //today is the last of the current month
    //put you function here
  }
}
```